# how to remove a string from bs4 results?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

EDIT: Ok here is the code i am using, the usps tracking number only has the address of a post office.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tRef=fullpage&tLc=1&text28777=&tLabels=03030130000309293695"

s = requests.Session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131     Safari/537.36'
r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")


for Status, Location, Time in map(None, soup.find_all("span", {"class":"info-text"}), soup.find_all("td", { "class":"location"})[1:], soup.find_all("td", { "class":"date-time"})):
    print Time.get_text().strip()
```

This is the output i am getting.

```
January 24, 2017

                                                        ,
                                                        7:13 am
```

This is what i want it to look like.

```
January 24, 2017,

7:13
```

also here is the html i am scraping.

```
<td class="date-time">
    <p>
        January 13, 2017
        ,
        2:09 pm
    </p></td>
<td class="status">
```

Comment: better show one `Status` and `Location` and expected result. If you want to remove text with constant size then use slicing `text[start:end]`. Or use `split(' ', 1)` to split text on first space. `rsplit(' ',1)` to split on last space (`r`=right). BTW: you can also use `replace()` if you what to remove the same word.

Comment: Maybe first check what you get with `find_all()[1:]` and what you get with `map()` - Maybe you shouldn't use `[1:]`, or you expect too much - you have only one date. Better create minimal, working example so we could run it. Now we can't help - we can't read in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

By default `.strip()` method strips away only whitespace, while in your case you most likely have a mix of newlines and whitespace, to remedy this try changing:

```
r = Status.get_text().strip().encode('utf-8')
# to
r = Status.get_text().strip(' \n').encode('utf-8')
```

`' \n'` - is made up from two characters, a white space and `\n` which stands for newline. Any leading or following of these characters will be stripped away.